# How do I access props received by a spread operator?

Tags: reactjs

I don't understand what's happening here.
Here I am just passing an object as a prop.

[Passing props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP024.png)

[Here I am taking it as a param.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpOKK.png)

[Here I am consoling it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMj04.png)

This is the expected behavior.

But now look at what happens when I use the spread operator on the props before consoling it.

[Using spread operator on props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c29B2.png)

[Consoling it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND9rT.png)

I am guessing this is because I am consoling out the actual 'props' object, but when I try to console out 'test', it gives me undefined. Why is 'test' undefined'?

If I just pass to a component the following: `test={'testing'}`, and then whenever I'm invoking the component, I do `(...props)`, now, what am I expected to get? Or if I pass an object 'test' instead, should I not get the object properties?

Note, I am using storybook in this particular example to invoke pass and invoke the component, but the storybook is irrelevant here. This is a question about React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you spread your props in your react component, you can see that you actually get back an array where as index 0 contains your test object which you can access via props[0].

I would recommend that you do not use the spread operator on your props in your component since this is basically cloning your object. You lose your reference to the object you passed into it, you might not want to do that. Have you a specific use case for this?

Comment: But why does spreading the props gives me an array, and not the object directly? If I pass `test={testObject}`, spreading test `...test` gives me the `testObject`, so why is the same thing not happening with `props`??

Comment: I am examining a code other people have worked on. I am trying to understand what's happening here.

Comment: You get back an array when spreading your ...props because you dont have a specific type specified (thank js for that) and normally your props would be of type any[]. When you now spread your props it will be put in that array (any[]). If you wrap it in an object like Shiva showed, than js knows that an object will be returned.

Comment: By `type` you mean a `type` specified in the `propTypes`? So, you're saying that using the spread operator on `props` returns an array .. of what? What are these other objects inside the array beside the prop that I passed? And so, if I use a spread operator, the 3 objects inside are returned, and .. why is this wrapped inside a deconstruction braces?

Comment: when you use plain js then your components passed props are of the type any[]. If you pass now an object to your component like <Carousel test={yourTestObj} /> then yourTestObj will be added to your components props array. ( Think of it like a script where you can pass n amount of arguments. )  For the question of what props return an array of what , if you mean which type is returned just think of it as that.. array === object so it really doesnt matter of which type it is. The nuance here is if you spread your object in your components props they get added to the props array.

Comment: For your last question regarding the 3 elements in your array: 1. is your object, 2: is just an empty object and this is because (not sure tho) its for more arguments / parameters you might pass (if you add more params to your props, this empty object will always be added to the end again).  3. looks like some react props got added there not sure why tho

Comment: Still not 100% clear, but I think I understand enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use below syntax to get this fixed

```
 export function Corousel({ test, ...props }) {
   console.log(test);
   return <>{JSON.stringify(test)}</>;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what does `{ ...props }` do? How are you deconstructing props, when there is no prop called `prop` being passed? I don't get this. If you pass to a component `test={'testing'}`, and then do {test}, you're deconstructing the `props` object, and getting only the `test` prop, but how are you deconstructing `props` when you are not passing it? And why are you accessing it with `props.test` even after the deconstruct? I am looking for an explanation more than a solution.

Comment: basically, React props is an object of properties passed through the JSX Element. If you want to access a specific property , you need to destruct it with exact matching name and rest you can spread to other variable as shown in above example. In your case if you want to access `test`,  you have to destruct the object to `test` variable

Comment: Yes, I know props is an object containing the passed props, that's exactly why I am asking why are you using spread operator on props while deconstructing it at the same time `{...props}`? When I do `...props`, why am I not getting the other passed props? And what happens when you use spread operator inside a deconstruction braces? What are you getting back?